# Работа с шаблонами, при добавлении комментариев через AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, twig

Не могу понять как использовать шаблон. TWIG.JS и  TWIG на вьюхах.
Вот контроллер он ищет шаблоны:

подключаю контроллер через script

```
 public function index()
{
    $views = config('view.paths') ;
    foreach ($views as $view_path) {
           $templates = new \FilesystemIterator($view_path . "/shared/",\FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS );
           foreach ($templates as $template) {
               $templateComment = [
                   "comment" => file_get_contents($template)
               ];
               return 'var twig_templates = '.json_encode($templateComment);
           }
       }


}
```

Далее JS:

```
var body = $('textarea[name=body]').val();
var _token = $('input[name=_token]').val();
var article_id = $('input[name=article_id]').val();
var user_id = $('input[name=user_id]').val();
var user_name = $('input[name=user_name]').val();
var path = 'http://simpleblog/';
var comment_template = twig({
    data: twig_templates['comment']
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : path+'new-comment',
    data: {body:body,_token:_token, article_id: article_id, user_id: user_id,user_name:user_name},
    success : function(data){

        var result = comment_template.render(data);

    }
},"json");

var body = $('textarea[name=body]').val("");

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Как использовать данные из json, вставить в шаблон и во вью?
Примеры пожалуйста, ничего похожего не могу найти, опыта с JS толком нету.

View: http://pastie.org/10346899